# Can I activate all child hover states at the same time?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-selectors, hover

I hope someone can help. I am trying to create a link with a background image in one div and and text in another. I am trying to create hover states for each which activate as soon as the parent is hovered over, which currently i'm having difficulty with. So far I have only managed to activate individual hover states.
Any ideas as to how I can solve the problem? Or is it even possible?

```
<style>
.pf_block {
float:left;
width:33.33333333333333%;
background-color:#6f2788;
}

.pf_img_1 { 
width: 100%;
height: 313px;
background-image: url(http://kay-dee-emm.com/test/images/pf_vectors.jpg); 
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: none;
}



.pf_title {
position:relative;
width: 95%;
padding:10px 0 10px 5%;
font: 28px /* 48px / 16px */ 'Quicksand', Arial, sans-serif;
color:#f7f56b;
}


.pf_img_1 {
transition:0.4s;
}


.pf_link_1 .pf_img_1:hover {
opacity:0.6;
}

.pf_link_1 pf_title:hover {
opacity:1;
color:#red;
}

</style>    
<a class="pf_link_1" href="">
<div class="pf_block">
<div class="pf_img_1"> </div>
<div class="pf_title">
    <p>
    Vectors
    </p>
</div>
</div></a>
```

Comment: You have a couple of typos in your question code, namely `pf_title:hover` and `#red`. They have been corrected in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this by specifying `:hover` on the parent instead of each child:

```
.pf_link_1:hover .pf_img_1 {
opacity:0.6;
}

.pf_link_1:hover .pf_title {
opacity:1;
color:red;
}
```

These are still two separate CSS rules with their own declarations, but hovering over the parent will correctly activate both rules simultaneously.